# Access Denied C# Winform Closing

Tags: c#, winforms

For some unknown reason, a bug showed up on my application.
The application is a automatic webpage visitor using GeckoFX C#.

Basicly, I can't close the application properly. 
If I use the Winform Close button the application disappears however is still running in background. 
I had a solution, just in case something like this appears however that one is failing as well.

```
private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var process in Process.GetProcessesByName("Nodlweb"))
        {
            process.Kill();
        }
        foreach (var process in Process.GetProcessesByName("NodlwebUpdater"))
        {
            process.Kill();
        }

    }
```

Now when I press the close button I get Access Denied even if I run the application as Administrator. I also stopped all timers, disposed gecko browser and added `Application.ExitThread();` but the application still wont shutdown properly.

The only change I made lately was adding http://github.com/Fody/Costura to the project. I removed it but the error persists.

It's been almost two days, I can't find the problem. Maybe someone had something similar and guide me ?

Thank you.

Comment: How about Environment.Exit(0) to close your WinForms-Application?

Comment: That worked, thank you. Any idea why is happening ?

Comment: Actually no, this is just how I usually quit my applications when I have other threads or processes still running.

Comment: I see, thanks anyway, Feel free to post an answer so i can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
Environment.Exit(0);
```

to close your WinForms-Application?